# In wso2 identity server saml, how to disable jsession id

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

In wso2 identity server how can I disable jsession id for saml SSO. As in my case of authentication flow doesn't require jsessionid and it affects if jsessionid is present. I tried to search in source code of wso2 is extension `identity-inbound-auth-saml` but I couldn't able to find.

Comment: Can you explain your exact requirement? JSESSIONID cookie in the Identity Server is not used to track any session. So it should not cause any issue.

Comment: @MadurangaSiriwardena while integrating between application, i mean incase of inter-application communication as the jsessionid created by one application won't allow other application it will create issue that's why we decided to disable jsessionid. And also even though saml is stateless but without jsession id specifying jsessionid we can't able to call acess the resource.

Comment: So shouldn't it be disabled by the application? Identity Server doesn't need a JSESSIONID from the application to handle any session related functionality.

Comment: thank you for the reply, instead of disabling for each application we thought of disabling jsession id at identity server level. So, I am searching in https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-inbound-auth-saml for disabling but no where I found configuration for disabling

Comment: I may not have fully understood your requirement. But AFAIU, you don't need to do anything for JSESSIONID, since Identity Server does not care about a JSESSIONID cookie. So there is nothing required to do to ignore a JSESSIONID cookie.

Comment: because wso2 identity server creates jsessionid and saml token  as cookie, so what I'm trying to implement is statelssness in application. So, whenever I recieve the request after login I'm trying to query based on session index, and once it authenticates it will give response or redirects to login page. But if any condition the session index is not there but jsession id exists there would be continuous redirection between application and identity server.

Comment: @MadurangaSiriwardena I have doubt like how the browser sends the saml token, as in storage I have seen there is nothing stored as saml token

Answer (score 0):

JSESSION_ID is a cookie. All the rules applicable for cookie applies for it. Browser does not send JSESSION_ID cookie to any host+path pair which is not matching. Hence there is no chance of having any side effect to any other application having the same cookie name (JSESION_ID).

If it means you host your application in the Identity Server itself, then please move it to separate Tomcat. Identity Server is never meant to host other applications.

There is no requirement or capability to disable the JSSESSION_ID as it is provided by Tomcat library used by the Identity Server. However it may be removed in future version as Identity Server does not use it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!, suppose if two service providers are registered for saml sso, then if we login into any one application then without login we can access another application as sso is configured. But if we do application to application integration there jsessionid will affect right? as another application expects jsession id. If I disable jsession id in wso2IS tomcat then will it be disabled. I have deployed applications in different servers.

Comment: No, it will not have any effect on SSO case with or without JSESSION_ID. Identity Server maintains a different session for SSO.

Comment: No configuration to do so, as it is not necessary.

Comment: Better look for Tomcat source code for JSESSION_ID related things